# Is it possible to use Google Spreadsheets to post to a web service?

Tags: google-sheets

I was wondering, as a thought experiment, if it were possible to use Google Spreadsheets to post to a web service.

For example imagine you created a spreadsheet for guests attending a party with columns - first name, last name, allergies, meal preferences since it is so easy to share and sync you send a link to it to everyone you can think of. But being a geek you would like the data to populate a MySQL server (or whatever) so you can create a fancy website or reminder or social thingy (or whatever).

Is this possible? I have tried reading the API but it does not appear to be but maybe I have missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, populating an external service should be possible in a few different ways, all involving Google Apps Scripts:

1. By using the [JDBC service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc) to populate an external database directly
2. By using the [URLFetch service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_urlfetchapp) to call an external web service
3. By pulling data from the spreadsheet from an external app

In any case, you would need to set up a trigger script that will run [when a response is submitted to your spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers).

Option 1 might be out of the question if your database is behind a firewall. If you're not keen on doing a lot of Google Apps scripting, a good compromise could be to have a small trigger script ping an external web service to notify it of the new data. The external service would then poll the Google Spreadsheet for data, [using for example the XML API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670338/exporting-from-google-spreadsheet-to-xml).

You say it's just a thought experiment for now (too bad - it sounds like a fun project), but in any case I would really recommend reading up on [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/). It is a fairly new feature in Google Docs/Drive, and really makes it possible to create quite powerful webapps.

Comment: Nice answer! I have been mulling over this in my head for months now - I just had that itch that "I should be able to do this". Thanks. Have you tried this before or known anyone who has?

Comment: I have been doing stuff with triggers, and have played with URLFetch, but I haven't done exatcly what you're trying to accomplish. But as I said, it sounds like a cool thing to do!

Comment: Oh, and again: You really should look into Google Apps Script. That has helped me scratch a lot of itches.